# how to make use the .rela.dyn to trigger elf loader for aarch64?

Tags: linux, gcc, gnu, elf, arm64

I have implemented packer of x86_64 shared library.
Briefly,

1. a simple xor-loader is injected to a shared library (by creating a new section)
2. the rela.dyn act as an entrypoint for the shared library
3. the rela.dyn entry is patched such that it points to the address of the loader.
4. once the shared library is called, the xor-loader is triggered and decrypt the .text section.

The mechanism works fine for the x86_64 shared library.
The rela.dyn tricks is borrowed from
https://github.com/0xN3utr0n/Noteme/blob/master/injection.c

However, this mechanism failed on aarch64.
I found that

1. if I xor-ed the .text section, the xor-loader is bypassed

   - I got Illegal instruction (core dumped), since the .text section has not been decrypted by the xor-loader. (confirmed by inspecting the .text section by gdb)
   - I have the loader objdump-ed, the loader is intact.
2. if I don't xor the .text section, the xor-loader is called and work normally. (But the decryption is wrong, since the .text section has not been xor-ed beforehand).

Question:

1. What could have possible went wrong in aarch64 ?

The result of `readelf` for aarch64 shared library is provided below.
`libtest.so` is the library before packing.
While `libtest_packed.so` is the library after packing.

Here is the result of `readelf --relocs libtest.so`

```
Relocation section '.rela.dyn' at offset 0x550 contains 7 entries:
000000010df0  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    780
000000010df8  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    738
000000011018  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    11018
000000010fc8  000300000401 R_AARCH64_GLOB_DA 0000000000000000 _ITM_deregisterTMClone + 0
000000010fd0  000400000401 R_AARCH64_GLOB_DA 0000000000000000 __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.17 + 0
000000010fd8  000500000401 R_AARCH64_GLOB_DA 0000000000000000 __gmon_start__ + 0
000000010fe0  000700000401 R_AARCH64_GLOB_DA 0000000000000000 _ITM_registerTMCloneTa + 0
```

the functions corresponding to the first 3 entries are:

```
0000000000000780 t frame_dummy
0000000000000738 t __do_global_dtors_aux
000000000011018 d __dso_handle
```

here is the result of `readelf --relocs libtest_packed.so`

```
Relocation section '.rela.dyn' at offset 0x550 contains 7 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000010df0  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    11028
000000010df8  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    738
000000011018  000000000403 R_AARCH64_RELATIV                    11018
000000010fc8  000300000401 R_AARCH64_GLOB_DA 0000000000000000 _ITM_deregisterTMClone + 0
000000010fd0  000400000401 R_AARCH64_GLOB_DA 0000000000000000 __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.17 + 0
000000010fd8  000500000401 R_AARCH64_GLOB_DA 0000000000000000 __gmon_start__ + 0
000000010fe0  000700000401 R_AARCH64_GLOB_DA 0000000000000000 _ITM_registerTMCloneTa + 0
```

As you can see, the first entry is overwritten by the address of the loader.